# insert values not working in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

I have created two tables, employee and department. Now, in the department table, I assigned a foreign key and a PK is assigned for the employee table. If view data, Ii can join the table.

How to write the query in PHP for insert and update?

My query:

```
?php
include "connect.php";
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $fname  = $_POST["fname"];
    $dept   = $_POST["dept"];


    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO employee ( fname, department)
            (SELECT fname, department FROM employee LEFT JOIN department ON employee.id=department.dept_id) values ( '$fname', '$dept')");

    if($result)
        {
            echo "<script>alert('New employee register successfully!')</script>";
            echo "<script>window.open('register.php','_self')</script>";
        }
    else 
        {
            echo "<script>alert('something went wrong!')</script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: you want to write join query for inserting and updating or just for selecting values

Comment: Check for errors. Connection, table- and column-names.

Comment: can you provide more code like how are you declaring $fname and $dept?

Comment: dept column in foreign key so how can i join the tables and insert values

Comment: You asked same question 2 Hours Before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218055/how-to-insert-values-foreign-key-assign-column-in-mysqli

Comment: But i never got it answer .
thats why again ask??
But still now no answer

Comment: You are getting values `$fname` and `$dept`. Insert it. Why you want to join it ? What you will get after joining ? I am not understanding why you want to join query and insert.

Comment: **Question Unclear**

Comment: Because $dept column is another table foreign key assigned

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO employee (`fname`, `dept`)
VALUES ('$fname','$dept')");
if($result)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('New employee register successfully!')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('register.php','_self')</script>";
    }
```

// You Forget ( `` ) sign in values

Comment: `` sign is optional unless you used some reserved word for table and column names.

Comment: what you mean by join in insert query please explain your issue in brief sarathi

Comment: Sorry sir, below mentioned  query to show the values

 SELECT employee.fname, department.department from employee INNER JOIN department ON employee.id=department.dept_id

how can i insert values thats all

Comment: any body know that answer